# How to add a profile picture to Deedy-Resume CV

Tags: diagrams, cv

Newbie TEX user, having trouble adding a profile picture to my CV (based on Deedy-Resume template)

```
\begin{document}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%TITLE SECTION
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

\smash{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{snow_circle.png}}  % <<<- I added this for picture 
\namesection{Debarghya}{Das}{ % Your name
\urlstyle{same}\url{http://debarghyadas.com} \\ % Your website, LinkedIn profile or other web address
\href{mailto:dd367@cornell.edu}{dd367@cornell.edu} | 607.379.5733 % Your contact information
}
```

But, this results in half the picture showing up at the top left corner. 
[image]
Could anybody help me make it look something like, 
[image]

Will be even more thankful if you could also tell me how to split the name field into two lines. My name is rather long and I would like it to rather be in two lines instead of one. So that it looks like below :

```
PICTURE              ARAVINDH
                     SAMPATHKUMAR
                    other details
```

Here is the code for /namesection in the .cls file,

```
\newcommand{\namesection}[3]{ % Defines the command for the main heading
\centering{ % Center the name
\fontsize{40pt}{60pt} % Font size
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont #1 % First name font
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #2 % Last name font
} \\[5pt] % Whitespace between the name and contact information
\centering{ % Center the contact information
\color{headings} % Use the headings color
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}    {14pt}\selectfont #3} % Contact information font
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{headings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}} % Horizontal rule
\vspace{-5pt} % Reduce whitespace after the rule slightly
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Where can we find this template?

Comment: Here is the original template : http://www.latextemplates.com/template/deedy-resume-cv

Comment: I'm sorry, but it produces no file on my system (some problem with fonts).

Comment: The template does not support a profile picture by default, sorry.

Comment: @Bernard I added my working copy of the TeX and files into a GitHub repo available here: https://github.com/aravindhsampath/resume_deedy     It should also contain the necessary fonts that came with the template.

Comment: @Johannes_B Thanks for looking into the TeX template. But, is there no way to add an image to any document? Is this template actively trying to prevent me from adding a picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code to obtain what you want, partly with trial and errors:

Add this to your preamble. The `\namesection` command is redefined with one optional argument (the options for `includegraphics) and 4 mandatory argyments (the first argument being the name of the graphic file):

```
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{ >{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\renewcommand{\namesection}[5][]{% Defines the command for the main heading
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cX} % Center the name
\raisebox{-0.7\height}[0pt][0pt]{\includegraphics[#1]{#2}} & \fontsize{40pt}{60pt} % Font size
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Lig}\selectfont #3 % First name font
\fontspec[Path = fonts/lato/]{Lato-Hai}\selectfont #4 % Last name font
 \\[5pt] % Whitespace between the name and contact information
 &\parbox{\linewidth}{\color{headings}% Use the headings color
\fontspec[Path = fonts/raleway/]{Raleway-Medium}\fontsize{11pt}{14pt}\selectfont\centering #5}\smallskip
\end{tabularx}\\ % Contact information font
\noindent\makebox[\linewidth]{\color{headings}\rule{\paperwidth}{0.4pt}} % Horizontal rule
\vspace{-5pt} % Reduce whitespace after the rule slightly
}
```

Usage:

```
\namesection[height=2cm]{YosemiteSam}% Your graphic file + optional argument for \includegraphics
{Aravindh}{Sampathkumar}{ % Your name
\href{mailto:aravindh@fastmail.com}{aravindh@fastmail.com } \\+1 864 643 8729% Your contact information
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: Strangely, just reusing the code snippet you posted yields an overlapping image and text to me. as in here [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/nma5mXe.png)    Do you have any idea how I set an absolute location for the image, and then center the text amongst the rest of the space?

Comment: Probably your image is larger than mine. To solve your problem one would have to patch the  `\namesection` command. I'll try post a code in a moment. What's more strange to me is I am unable to compile your file from within my editor, and it works fine from the command line!

Answer (score 0):

For me following the code solved my problem.

```
\includegraphics[height=3cm]{aditya.jpg} 

\vspace{-24mm}
\namesection {Aditya}{Sharma}
{ % Your name
\href{mailto:aditya.narayana.sharma@gmail.com}{aditya.narayana.sharma@gmail.com} \\+91 9001788368% Your contact information
}
```

Be sure to include line space between \includegraphics and \vspace.